# MySQL is using swap memory while I have plenty of free RAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, memory, configuration

I have a 6 GB buffer pool size for my database; however, `mysqld` process is moving to swap while there is plenty of RAM available. I think pool size and pages along with pool of reads and pool of read requests should be tuned to avoid such situation.

Below is my current configuration:

```
[fuad@damra mysql]$ free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7872       7138        734          0        304        678
-/+ buffers/cache:       6155       1717
Swap:        32767        456      32311


mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool%';
+---------------------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name                         | Value       |
+---------------------------------------+-------------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status        | not started |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status        | not started |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data         | 316153      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data         | 5179850752  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty        | 20          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty        | 327680      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed      | 51645307    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free         | 75279       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc         | 1776        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total        | 393208      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd     | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead         | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests      | 26268346860 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads              | 496         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free          | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests     | 207971337   |
+---------------------------------------+-------------+

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 8              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 6442450944     |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Do I need to tune these values to achieve better results and to not let MySQL switch to swap disk unless RAM is fully utilized?

This is a dedicated database server holding two MySQL schemas. Both schemas are serving the same application (one schema is to store statistics).

I can't change *swappiness* as this is not an option for the VMware administrator. As for RAM, I have 734+678 (cached memory can be re-used).

I have Java installed on this server to serve the JDBC driver between my application and MySQL.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago).

Comment: Set `swappiness = 1` (or higher -- up to 10, do not use 0)  and review the overcommit variables. 
Actually, you are not plenty of memory as free is only 734 MB free and only 678 MB of the total usage are cached. So, probably you are not plenty as you think or your db activity is higher than you expected :)

Comment: Did you change other settings?  For example, `query_cache_size` should be either 0 or no more than 50M.

Comment: If you would like more analysis, please provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` (perhaps via a postit via).

Comment: Are other applications running on the same server?  It looks like the buffer_pool is about 80% of RAM; recommend 70% of _available_ RAM.

Answer (score 1):

`Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free` / `Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total` shows about 15% free. Given the low number of dirty pages and the very low `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads` vs `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads_requests` you probably could trim your buffer_pool size.

`Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free == 0` is perfectly acceptable if you aren't reading from disk frequently (low Innodb_buffer_pool_reads).